# Content is going under Header and Footer

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The `content` between `header` and `footer` is going under them. I've tried setting `flex-start` and `flex-end` to `header` and `footer` but they don't go to the `absolute top`. They are stacked above and below the content.

The style of the header is

```
.Header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The style of the Footer is

```
.Footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The style of the content(if it helps) is

```
.Content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Also Add HTML Code here

Comment: Please share complete code snippet (HTML and CSS both) in order to understand your problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely-positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document.

You can either add margins to the top and bottom of the content to add space for the header and footer, or switch to using ["sticky" positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).

```
.Header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.Footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header is using `position: absolute` so its out of flow. Use `position: relative` or add a top padding/margin with the height of your header for your content.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #707070;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e9e;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](https://codepen.io/shahemm/pen/poWENbY?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="Header">Header</div>
  <div class="Content">Content</div>
  <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }

.Content {
  background-color:red;
  height:90vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.Footer {
  background-color:green;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
    height:5vh
}

.Header {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  height:5vh
}
```

for more information about The position Property visit :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can give top and bottom padding to the content equal to the height of header and footer

```
.Content {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom:40px ;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```